# How can I change the opacity of an element on a page when an image element is clicked/active?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the opacity of a div element when you click on an img element, using JavaScript or jQuery. I don't know if it's possible to do this with CSS or HTML, but if you know how to, please feel free to tell me! Anyways, here's the code I have right now;

```
<div class="scene" id="scene">the text</div> 
<!--the text element i'm trying to change-->
```

```
<img src="zyro-image (7) (1).png" id="look" class="look"><img> 
<!--the img element; if it's clicked/active it changes the div element's opacity-->
```

**the styles ⬇️**

```
.scene{
    font-family: 'Common Pixel', sans-serif; 
    background-color:black; 
    border: 2px; 
    color: white; 
    padding-top: 10px; 
    padding-bottom: 25px; 
    width: 350px; 
    opacity: 0;
}

<!--____________________-->

.look{
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: -685px;
    margin-top: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: top, 1s;
}

.look:hover{
    top: -692px;
}
```

## Here are some things I tried;

(I got most of these answers  - if not all of them - from stackoverflow)

**1.**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$('.look').active(function(){
  $('.scene').css('opacity', '1');
 });
</script>
```

This one did not work, it looked as if it did nothing. No difference.

**2.**

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        document.getElementById('scene').setAttribute("class", "scene2");
    }
</script>

<!--________________-->

<styles>
.scene2{
    font-family: 'Common Pixel', sans-serif; 
    background-color:black; 
    border: 2px; 
    color: white; 
    padding-top: 10px; 
    padding-bottom: 25px; 
    width: 350px;
    opacity: 1;
}
</styles>
```

This one had the same result as the last one, no difference.

**3.**

```
<script>
        function change_css(){
            document.getElementById('result').style.cssText = 'font-family:'Common Pixel', sans-serif; background-color:black; border:2px; color:white; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:25px; width:350px; opacity:1;';
        }
    </script>
```

I don't even think I *need* to say it anymore. It. Did. Not. Work.

Comment: @CanO'Spam, answers go down there.

Comment: Clicked and active are two very different things. Which do you need? If both, you'll have to handle both differently, as you'll need to monitor for the end of the active state on blur or whatever.

Comment: Try changing the test code. If the default opacity is 1, and you change it to 1,  there is no difference to see.

Comment: @traktor yeah it still did nothing-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image should have the onclick eventlistener which will trigger the change of opacity:

```
<img src="yoursrc" onclick="changeOpacity()"/>
```

Give your div an id:

```
<div id="mydiv">I'm a div</div>
```

Then use this function which will get your div by id and add your changed opacity class to div:

```
function changeOpacity() {document.getElementById('mydiv').classList.add('opacity-low')}
```

CSS Class:

```
.opacity-low {opacity: 0.5;}
```

There might be a prettier way to do this but i'm not an expert in plain JS.

Comment: also i realized i should have also made the background color transparent not only the text

Answer (score 0):

Set DIV's opacity after IMG click:

```js
$("#img").click(() => $("#div").css("opacity", 0.5))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div">I need opacity</div>
<img id="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
```

Or better with CSS

```
<style>
   .opacityClass {opacity:0.5;}
</style>

...
$("#img").click( () => $("#div").addClass("opacityClass") )
```

Comment: idk why but when i tried to do this it didn't work .-.

I literally tried everything why isn't this working

Comment: Clearly it does work (and clearly you haven't tried _everything_).